# How to select average from row result on oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, select, average

I am trying to calculate average from the result then join them.

My main query is here:

```
 SELECT
      A.USERNAME,
      A.TOTAL,
      A.MATH 

    FROM 
    (SELECT 
        B.USERNAME,     
       COUNT(CLASS_ID) TOTAL,   
       SUM(CASE WHEN ROOM_ID = '1001' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MATH
        FROM    A LESSON, STUDENT B
         WHERE  
          A.USERNAME = B.USERNAME                    
        AND A.CREATED_DATE >= TO_DATE(:created_date ,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
        AND A.CREATED_DATE < TO_DATE(:created_end_date ,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
        GROUP BY B.USERNAME 
        ORDER BY TOTAL DESC) A
```

It gives me:

```
|USERNAME|TOTAL|MATH|           
|John    |  480|159 |
|Dave    |  360|120 |
|Sarah   |  540|130 |
|James   |  361|185 |
|Kim     |  640|92  |
|Matt    |  11 |2   |
|Jane    |  8  |1   |
```

But I want to get like this:

```
|USERNAME|TOTAL|AVG_FROM_TOTAL|MATH|AVG_FROM_MATH|              
|John    |  480|      476     | 159|     137     |
|Dave    |  360|      476     | 120|     137     |
|Sarah   |  540|      476     | 130|     137     |
|James   |  361|      476     | 185|     137     |
|Kim     |  640|      476     |  92|     137     |
```

It's calculated manually like this

- (480+360+540+361+640/5 = 476) /It will be removed the user Matt and Jane
  because too low from others/
- (159+120+130+185+92/5 = 137) /removed Matt and Jane result/

How can I create query that I want to calculate? Is it possible to calculate average from the result?

Comment: Explain what you mean by "too low".  I couldn't add that logic, since there was no logical description of "too low".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple as this:

```
SELECT A.USERNAME
     , A.TOTAL
     , AVG(A.TOTAL) OVER () AS avg_total
     , A.MATH
     , AVG(A.MATH) OVER () AS avg_math
  FROM (your derived table) A
 WHERE A.TOTAL > 20
;
```

These are window functions.

Feel free to remove any rows you wish from the derived table or after the derived table in the outer WHERE clause (which you can add).

Comment: It's working :) but How can I remove above 2 rows? Do you mean may put something like this `A.TOTAL > 20`

Comment: @Solution Sure, you can add that logic if that's what "too low" means.